# Reverse contraposition: how to prove $(\neg Q \implies \neg P)\vdash(P \implies Q)$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Contraposition states $(P \implies Q)\vdash(\neg Q \implies \neg P)$. But how to prove when premise and conclusion are reversed, namely how to prove $(\neg Q \implies \neg P)\vdash(P \implies Q)$?

I have nice example of this:

If rains, then the floor is wet. And, of course, if floor is not wet, then it doesn't rain. (Observe that reverse statement is not true: *if floor is wet, then it rains* is a false statement.)

If the floor is not wet, then it doesn't rain. (Again, observe that reverse statement is not true: *if it doesn't rain, then the floor is not wet* is a false statement).

Comment: Can you substitute $P,Q$ in the first formula for $\neg Q, \neg P$ in the second, and use double negation introduction/elimination?

Comment: That's it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to prove this is by using a proof tree. You start with the negation of your formula then apply some contradiction-hunting rules to show that that negation cannot be true; here:

[image]

[Here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((%C2%ACQ%E2%86%92%C2%ACP)%E2%86%92(P%E2%86%92Q))) is where the tree was generated.

Comment: Nice as general algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple heuristic argument for my own question. This is of course, just an intuition not the 'real' proof, but I believe that such basic results must have common-sense explanations for all self-learners, as am I.

Notation $A_1, A_2, ... \implies B$ says that if some $A_i$'s hold then $B$ must also hold; therefore the consequence of every $A_i$ is $B$ and other way around, causes of $B$ are all $A_i$'s.

Now, what about relations between $\neg B$ and $A_i$'s?  Other way to say $\neg B$ is that $B$ doesn't hold which is same as saying that consequence of some $A_i$'s doesn't hold. This implies that $A_i$ doesn't hold either because if some $A_i$'s do indeed hold we would get $B, \neg B$ at the both holds at the same time, which is not possible.

To prove my question, as said in comments, we can just set $\neg Q := P, \neg P := Q$ and using $\neg \neg A = A$ we are done.